# How to pick some information in some tag with XStream

Tags: xstream

I need to pick some information from a **XML** and I'm using **Xstream**.
I need some information from books but not every information.

The XML:

```
<Origin>
 <MsgData>
  <Transaction>
   <Book class="R">
     <Title>info 1</Title>
     <Author>info 2</Author>
     <Pages>info 3</Pages>
       <other infos>some other info that i dont need </other infos>
     <Local class="R">
        ...
        more info that i dont need
        ...
     </Local>
    </Book>
  </Transaction>
 </MsgData>
</Origin>
```

I tried to use the `ignoreUnknownElements()` but when I convert the **XML** to the "Origin" class that I created the attributes from the object are all nulls.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm using some things to make it work. I created every **class** until de Book **class**, so it's like that:

```
public class Origin { 

  private MsgData msgData;

}

public class MsgData { 

  private Transaction transaction;

}

public class Transaction { 

  private Book book;

}

public class Book { 

 private String info1
 private String info2
 private String info3

}
```

After that I need to replace the class="R" inside the tag Book.
With the Xml I can do a *`replaceAll()`*

Than just do the *`alias`* and *`aliasField`* from the **XStream** created and use the *`ignoreUnknownElements()`*.

In the end just do the Cast

```
OriginfromXml = (Origin)xstreamCreated.fromXml(stringFromReplaceAll);
```

That's one solution, if someone has some better way to do it I post it.